# How to create horizontal scrolling menu with drop-down?

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to build a (possibly) CSS-only menu for an HTML5 page with the following requisites:

- menu should be an horizontal scrolling list (a top navbar), with scrolling buttons and no visible scrollbars
- first level menu items could have sub-items like a multiple nested drop-down menu

Visually:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| < |     Menu 1    |     Menu 2 +  |     Menu 3    |     Menu 4    | > |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      | menu 2.1   |
                      --------------
                      | menu 2.2 + |---------------
                      --------------  menu 2.2.1  |
                      | menu 2.1   |---------------
                      --------------  menu 2.2.2  |
                                   |---------------
```

where the *<* and *>* buttons scroll the main menu to the left or right (eventually opened sub items should **undrop** themselves).

I also would like to use CSS only (no JavaScript), but this is an option.

I've already spent lot of time for this and tests, but I didn't get any satisfying example.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle of what you currently have so we can help?

Comment: Sadly CSS has no onclick handlers, so an CSS only solution is not posible.

Comment: In effect, I tried to merge those 3 samples:  
  
[1] (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h)  
  
[2] (http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=tabs-with-dropdown-menus)  
  
[3] (https://codepen.io/srees/pen/pgVLbm)  
  
but I was not able to obtain a working page...

Answer (score 2):

You can do so quite easily.

You firs need a tree like structure using html lists :

```
<ul class="my-menu">
<li>
    TOP 1
    <ul>
        <li>
            1 - 1 >
            <ul>
                <li>
                    1 - 1 - 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    1 - 1 - 2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

You need to display the first level side by side to have the horizontal menu :

```
ul.my-menu > li {
    display :  inline-block;
}
```

For the second level we wish it to display just below the TOP1 text. So we will put it in absolute :

```
ul.my-menu > li > ul{
    position : absolute;
}
```

Now let's hide the second & Third level.

```
ul.my-menu > li > ul li{
    display: none;
}
```

Finally we can add the hover logic. Basically we will say if my parent "li" is hovered then display me.

```
ul.my-menu li:hover > ul > li {
    display: block;
}
```

Of course you need to work more on the display. The size & position of the boxes are very important as if not the mouse will leave the bounderies of the parent which will close the display.

Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9mbLabj4/1/

Comment: Thank you Oliver for your tips: I'll start right now to add it a scrolling effect!

Comment: In effect, I tried to merge those 3 samples:   http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h +
  http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=tabs-with-dropdown-menus + 
  https://codepen.io/srees/pen/pgVLbm